# How to call a list where the name of the list is in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coming back to python after a 10 year break and i appear to have forgotten the basics.

I've written the following code which works, but its lengthier than it should be.

```
def index():
    manu = request.args.get('manufacturer')
    print(manu)
    url = random.choice(get_list(manu))
    print(url)
    return render_template("index.html", url=url)


def get_list(list_name):
    if list_name == "audi":
        return [
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_01.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_02.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_03.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_04.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_05.jpg"
            ]
    else:
        return [
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bmw/bmw_01.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bmw/bmw_02.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bmw/bmw_03.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bmw/bmw_04.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bmw/bmw_05.jpg"
            ]
```

In my opinion that second function shouldn't be needed, because there ought to be a way to call the list of images by its name even though its in a variable gathered from the request. But what actually happens is the variable is a string and the choice is from that string.

Is there a simple way to call the list from the variable such that the lists would be in the same function?
This  sort of this, which I'm aware doesnt work:

```
url = random.choice(list(manu)
```

Comment: That last `url = random.choice(list(manu)`  needs a closing paren.

Comment: copy and paste error, but sharp eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to store your strings in a list in a dict. I.e

```
x = dict()
x["audi"] = [
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_01.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_02.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_03.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_04.jpg",
                "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_05.jpg"
            ]
```

Comment: great shout, i've got that working already. thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
def index():
    manu = request.args.get('manufacturer')
    print(manu)
    audi = "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/audi/audi_0"
    bmw = "https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bmw/bmw_0"
    _list = {
        "audi": [ audi + str(i) + ".jpg" for i in range(1, 6) ],
        "bmw": [ bmw + str(i) + ".jpg" for i in range(1, 6) ]
    }
    url = random.choice( _list[manu] )
    print(url)
    return render_template("index.html", url=url)
```

Since the URL of each image is the same except the image number we can create the list by storing a similar part into a variable.

And store URL into a dictionary using `audi` and `bmw` as a key. Dictionary will help us to easily call the list with key into the `random` method.

Comment: slick, thanks. I've used the method above but yours is a piece of code i'll remember for the future.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
def index():
    manu = request.args.get('manufacturer')
    print(manu)

    no_of_images_for_manu = {'audi': 10,
                             'bmw': 5}
    all_urls = dict()
    for manu, no_of_images in no_of_images_for_manu.items():
        if manu not in all_urls:
            all_urls[manu] = []

        for manu_index in range(1, no_of_images + 1):
            # Zero padding for manu_index using manu_index:02 only works for Python >= 3.6. For other versions the code
            # is different.
            all_urls[manu].append(f'https://cars-docker-images.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/{manu}/{manu}_{manu_index:02}.jpg')

    url = random.choice(all_urls[manu])
    return render_template("index.html", url=url)
```